# Is the formular "x is red" written in the first order language?

Tags: first-order-logic

I watched a video lecture on the set theory by the lecturer whom I respect the most. He provided an example of a property in the axiom schema of separation. He stated that in $S=\{x\in \{3,4\} |$x is red$\}$ the property "x is red" is good enough for the set to be defined. He said it could be any property, Russel Paradox is gone since we have $x\in\{3,4\}$. I understand why. The lecturer stated that this set is a null set, since the letters $3$ and $4$ were written in white color. But I also googled that the property should be built in the first-order logic language with only non-logical quantifier $\in$. **My first question is: does this property really built in the first-order logic language with only non-logical quantifier $\in$? Can we really make some extra definitions for what is red and construct this set? Second question, does the axiom in this variant (when a property is just any property like he said) always allow to avoid paradoxes? Or set theory language is a must for the construction of the property?**

Comment: Can sets of oranges be defined using ZFC and the first-order logic language with only non-logical quantifier $\in$? I am asking since in ZFC we build sets starting from a null set. Using ZFC and some definitions we can build natural and real numbers, but not oranges? Or sets of oranges too can be built in ZFC (just some extra definitions for oranges)?

Comment: No; oranges cannot  be defined using ZFC. Oranges are not mathematical objects.

Comment: "X is red" is written in the 1st order language. We can now create axioms: every object on earth equals to a single number (all these numbers should be different). So the set of oranges is defined? Where did i make a mistake?

Comment: If i can not create new axioms I can call it hypotheses in the 1st order language?

Comment: For sure you can create the FO theory of oranges, using the predicate $\text {Red}(x)$ and the axiom $\forall x \text {Red}(x)$. But this will be a new theory and not part of ZFC.

Comment: So coloured numbers are not defined in ZFC too. Thus the statement with a predicate Red(x) is also not a correct example of a property in the ZFC axiom of separation? This is incorrect on 28-40?: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfYP37x6bN4&list=PLAvgI3H-gclbnCZdLWpPUZnvlnrirzDa6&index=3

Comment: Or maybe the set S is still well defined in ZFC since elements in {3,4} actually have no color. So they are not red. Is the predicate  Red(x) well defined in set theory language?

Comment: The color red itself is not defined in ZFC. Thus we can not form the predicate Red(x) in ZFC?

Comment: No; as said above, we cannot "define" oranges and their properties in ZFC. We can build a dedicated FO theory for oranges with specific primitive predicates and axioms.